# Exact differentiation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

How it follows below after $9.4$ that "...and so $d\sigma^i=0$ for all $i$" ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, by hypothesis, $[e_j,e_k]$ vanishes for all $j,k$, it follows that
$$d\sigma^i(e_j,e_k)=-\sigma^i([e_j,e_k])=0$$
for all $j,k$, and then $d\sigma$ is identically zero as the $e_i$'s form a basis pointwisely.

The equation
$$d\sigma^i(e_j,e_k)=-\sigma^i([e_j,e_k])$$
follows from the direct application of Theorem 4.25 since $\sigma^i(e_l)$ is either constant equal to $1$ (if $l=i$) or $0$ (if $l\neq i$), as $\{\sigma^i\}$ is the dual basis of $\{e_i\}$. Therefore, the terms $e_j\sigma^i(e_k)$ and $-e_k\sigma^i(e_j)$ will vanish since they are derivations of constants.

Comment: Sorry, how $e_j\sigma^i(e_k)$ is a derivation ?

Comment: @user122424 $e_j$ and $e_k$ are derivations, and $\sigma^i(e_k)$ and $\sigma^i(e_j)$ are constant functions.

Comment: $e_j$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ ?

Comment: @user122424 No. $e_j$ is just a vector field. Any vector field $X$ satisfies $Xf=0$ if $f$ is a constant function. (A posteriori, you conclude that there are coordinates such that $e_j=\partial_j$ for all $j$, but this is what you want to conclude.)